# Array query and return

Tags: mongodb

My first adventure into Mongo. Please save me some time by answering the following. This is the schema.

```
"_id" : 1,
  "FullName" : "Full Name",
  "Email" : "email@email.com",
  "FacebookId" : NumberLong(0),
  "LastModified" : ISODate("2012-04-11T09:26:10.955Z"),
  "Connections" : [{
      "_id" : 7,
      "FullName" : "Fuller name",
      "Email" : "connections@email.com",
      "FacebookId" : NumberLong(0),
      "LastModified" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
    },

  ....
```

Given an id of a single top user, i'd like to return all of the Emails in the Connections array, and preferably, just the emails. What's the querystring? Much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get only values from the sub-objects in MongoDB.

If you do a query like this:

```
db.test.find({"_id": 1}, {"Connections.Email":1});
```

you will get this kind of response:

```
{ 
  "_id": 1, 
  "Connections" : [ {"Email":"connections@email.com"}, 
                    {"Email":"foo@example.com"} ] 
}
```

This is the closest you can get with a simple query and field selection from MongoDB.

You can then filter out the e-mails values in your code with a simple `foreach`.